# Returning after clicking a footnote in Kindle Cloud Reader

Tags: kindle, kindle-cloud-reader

After I click a footnote on the Kindle Cloud Reader, how can I go back to where I was? I found instructions for the [Kindle](http://lisalutz.com/books/footnotes-guide/), but not for the cloud reader.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

When you scroll the mouse over the text, in the lower left you'll see a left arrow... click that to go back to the page where you clicked the footnote link.

Comment: Great answer.  I have wondered how to do that for so long and never noticed that little arrow at the bottom -- instead only noticed the larger arrows within the text.

Comment: lol, I'm glad you found this useful, but I'd actually like to revise my answer given events that have transpired over last two years.  It's a horrible pain, but you should totally delete your amazon account.  They are a terrible corporation

(this is coming from someone with a kindle, years and years of multimedia locked behind their DRM, and many cloud computing services with AWS which I had to migrate)

It was a horrible pain, but it was very much worth it.

Comment: The back button (left arrow in lower left corner) does nothing when I click it. I've been trying to figure this out for years. Every web browser has supported the back button for decades. Why can't Amazon figure it out how to implement the back button on Kindle apps?

Comment: It only goes to the page on the left, not the originating page

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as this is such an old thread, but with recent questions about how to get back to where the original footnote link was, you must click on the number of the footnote. It took me a while to figure this out (2 years).

Comment: that works too! to address the downvoter: when you click the footnote number in the *text*, it takes you to the footnote. when you click the footnote number in the *footnote*, it takes you back to that point in the text.